# Display Online users in a chat application

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a chat application and in this application, i want to show online users in a chatroom. I have a database that records online users and it keeps changing whenever a new user comes. Whenever a users leaves, it is deleted from the database. Database consists of two columns: username and room. Database side works fine.

onlinelar.php:

```
<?php

$data = array();

        $current = $_GET['current'];

        $room = $_GET['room'];

        $getRoomUsers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `chat_users_rooms` WHERE `room` = '".$room."'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($getRoomUsers) != $current)
        {
            $data['numOfUsers'] = mysql_num_rows($getRoomUsers);    
        }
        else
        {
            $data['numOfUsers'] = $current; 
        }
        echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

online.js:

```
var numOfUsers = 0;
var room;

function chat(room2)
{
room = room2;   
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false 
});


function getuserlist() {


     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "onlinelar.php",
        data: {  
                'room': room,
                'current' : numOfUsers
              },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
                if (numOfUsers != data.numOfUsers) {
                numOfUsers = data.numOfUsers;

                $('#bu').html($("<strong id='bu'>"+ numOfUsers + "</strong>"));
            }




            setTimeout(getuserlist(),1);

        },
    });

}
```

And finally, the initializer of it in index.html:

----something

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

                var chat = new Chat(<?php echo $room;?>);
                chat.getuserlist();

            </script>
                      <strong id="bu">
                        <?php
                        echo $numOfUsers;
                        ?>
                        </strong>
```

------something

In here, i want to check database situation(rows of the certain room), and change the number of chatters in that room simultaneously. 'current' is for number of users and 'room' is for the name of the room.But there is no change even though the num of rows of database is changing. Which part i am missing?
Note: I have added online.js in index.php

Comment: brace yourself... database works fine until little bobby tables comes, h̤ͬ͆͊̔͒̔͝e̮̗͇̬ ͍̽͌̚͝c̙ͯ̌̿͑̇ͨ͘ȏ̷͉̟̼̟̰̞̻͌̓mͧ̊҉͍͈̟e̜͇͔̤̺̭͂͆̉͌ͪ̾͝s̼͎̜ͨ́͆́ͣ͟

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: **Go to this address to delete your chat table: `http://example.com/onlinelar.php?room='); DROP TABLE chat_users_rooms; --`**

Answer (score 0):

`$('#bu').html($("<strong id='bu'>"+ numOfUsers + "</strong>"));`

This line places a new element under your old one, what you want to do is replace the old one by calling

```
$('#bu').html(numOfUsers);
```

Also `setTimeout()` takes milliseconds so `1` is a really low value, you might want to start with `1000` and work from there.

**Edit:**
And `setTimeout()` takes a function as a param so you want to call:

```
setTimeout(getuserlist, 1000);
```